# Uploading a video to youtube using youtube Data API: Broken pipe (Errno::EPIPE)

Tags: ruby, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to upload a local video file to my youtube account using youtube data api.

Example: https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/ruby/upload_video.rb

Call:

```
$ ruby upload_video.rb --file video.mp4
```

I'm getting an error message:

```
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/buffering.rb:326:in `syswrite': Broken pipe (Errno::EPIPE)
from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/buffering.rb:326:in `do_write'
from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl/buffering.rb:344:in `write'
from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:202:in `copy_stream'
from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:202:in `send_request_with_body_stream'
from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/generic_request.rb:132:in `exec'
...
from upload_video.rb:73:in `main'
from upload_video.rb:91:in `<main>'
```

upload_video.rb (line 73):

```
videos_insert_response = client.execute!(
  :api_method => youtube.videos.insert,
  :body_object => body,
  :media => Google::APIClient::UploadIO.new(opts[:file], 'video/*'),
  :parameters => {
    :uploadType => 'resumable',
    :part => body.keys.join(',')
  }
)
```

Comment: Any luck? I'm facing similar problem with something else. It happens for me while uploading an audio file.

Comment: @Chirantan actually yes. See the solution. Good luck

Answer (score 10, accepted):

google-api-client uses faraday gem which default http adapter is Net::HTTP. And it seems it's not working properly. So we need to switch it to something else. I changed it to httpclient and now it works fine.
Just add this line somewhere in the beginning of your whatever.rb file (right after requiring google's libs):

```
Faraday.default_adapter = :httpclient
```

Full list of supported http adapters could be found here: https://github.com/lostisland/faraday#faraday

Comment: Thanks for this, it took me a while to get past this bug!

Comment: dude. I love you, thank you very much !! Note for others, put this high up, before the api client is created. inspecting the client you should see `Faraday::Adapter::HTTPClient`

Comment: Also, google-api-client moved away from Faraday, so using >= v0.9.0 should fix this issue as well.